# replacing cells of formlayout in vaadin

Tags: java, css, web, vaadin, form-layout

when i am using formlayout in vaadin with text fields it make the caption on text field at left to the text field , what about if i need the caption in right of text field

```
FormLayout fieldsLayout = new FormLayout();
    TextField userNameFld = new TextField("User Name:", true);
    userNameFld.setIcon(FontAwesome.USER);
    fieldsLayout.addComponent(userNameFld);
    PasswordField passwordFld = new PasswordField("Password:", true);
    fieldsLayout.addComponent(passwordFld);
    TextField companyFld = new TextField("Company Name:", true);
    fieldsLayout.addComponent(companyFld);
```

how can i replace the positions of caption and textfields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormLayout` has three columns: first for caption, second (middle) for error indicator and third for component (for example `TextField`). And this is fixed construction.

To change order of those columns you must build your own layout using one `VerticalLayout` and some `HorizontalLayout` for each row. In each row you could add `TextField` without caption and one `Label` on the right position.